# Laravel order by desc

Tags: database, laravel, sql-order-by

I'm trying to get this order by descend working, but for some reason an error keeps being thrown which is:

> `BadMethodCallException` in `View.php` line 387:
> Method `[orderBy]` does not exist on view.

I'm not sure why it can't find the `orderBy` method.

```
public function display()
{
    return view('users/timeline')
        ->with('user_name', 'body', 'location',
            'photo', 'visibility', 'created_at')
        ->with('posts', Posts::all());
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->get();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
Posts::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

Now you can use `orderByDesc` directly:

```
Posts::orderByDesc('created_at')->get();
```